# Config file: import localization error

Tags: powershell, configuration

I am trying to import a PowerShell config `.psd1` file. I tried two ways and both case I get the following error.

```
Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory .\ -FileName bootstrap.Config.psd1 -BindingVariable ConfigData
```

OR

```
 $ConfigData = Import-LocalizedData -File bootstrap.Config.psd1
```

I don't need any localization. I don't have the folder en-US. I just want to simply import configuration file `bootstrap.Config.psd1`

Error:-

```
Import-LocalizedData : Cannot find the Windows PowerShell data file
  'bootstrap.Config.psd1' in directory 'C:\backup\tools\en-US\', or
  in any parent culture directories.
At C:\bataBackup\tools\Eurostep.SAS.DataBackup.ps1:1 char:1
+ Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory .\ -FileName bootsr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\back up s...rap.Config.psd1:String) [Import-LocalizedData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportLocalizedData,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportLocalizedData
```

Update after the comments and new error:-

```
# Import config data  
if( Test-Path $PSScriptRoot"\Config.psd1")
{
   $ConfigData = Import-Module -Name $PSScriptRoot"\Config.psd1" # error
   $ConfigData = Import-Module -Name $PSScriptRoot"\Config.psm1" #  fine.
}
```

Error:-

> Import-Module : The specified module 'C:\tools\Config.psd1' was not
>   loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Why this error now?

Comment: If you don't care about localization, why are you using `Import-LocalizedData`?

Comment: I'm new in ps. I didn't find any other way to import it.

Comment: `Import-Module -Name Path\to\bootstrap.Config.psd1`

Comment: Assuming you are working in the `C:backup\tools` directory, try creating the folder `en-US` and then moving your .psd1 file to it.

Comment: Cannot repro. Commands like `Import-LocalizedData -FileName data.psd1 -BaseDirectory .` work for me. Are you sure the location '.' is actually yours? Are you sure the file name is correct?

Comment: `C:\backup\tools` and `C:\bataBackup\tools` are not the same. This looks suspicious. Where is your .psd1 file and what is the current location when you use '.'?

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the real path.

Comment: @ TheIncorrigible1 Please check the new error after using Import-Module -Name. Why it is happening.

Comment: So I believe  Import-Module -Name is to import module *.psm1, not for *.psd1. Or I don't know. Please, somebody, tell me how to import *.psd1, no localization required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the way. It should be as follows:-

```
$ConfigData = Import-PowerShellDataFile $PSScriptRoot"\Config.psd1 ";
```

It doesn't bother with the localization.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same type of error "Could not find data file "abc.psd1" in directory "c:/MyDirectory/en-us".  It turns out that there was a typo in my file name and the file truly did not exist.  The /en-us/ sent me on a wild goose chase looking for problems in the call.